# Only one radio button checked

Tags: html, radio-button

I want to make a list of four questions. On each question, you can only answer YES or NO. The problem is that although I've used radio input you can still select both YES and NO on each question.

```
<ul>
<li>Question 1      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="1yes"/>YES<input type="radio" name="1no"/>NO</form></li>
<li>Question 2      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="2yes" />YES<input type="radio" name="2no" />NO</form></li>
<li>Question 3      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="3yes" />YES<input type="radio" name="3no" />NO</form></li>
<li>Question 4      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="4yes" />YES<input type="radio" name="4no" />NO</form></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `name="yes_no"` into each of the radio buttons.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Question 1
    <form>
      <class="right"> <input type="radio" name="yes_no" />YES<input type="radio" name="yes_no" />NO</form>
  </li>
  <li>Question 2
    <form>
      <class="right"> <input type="radio" name="yes_no" />YES<input type="radio" name="yes_no" />NO</form>
  </li>
  <li>Question 3
    <form>
      <class="right"> <input type="radio" name="yes_no" />YES<input type="radio" name="yes_no" />NO</form>
  </li>
  <li>Question 4
    <form>
      <class="right"> <input type="radio" name="yes_no" />YES<input type="radio" name="yes_no" />NO</form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your names for the radios are different, if your names are different, html doesn't see the radios as a pair of radios, therefore allowing you to select two options.

One way to fix this is to do this,

```
<li>Question 1      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="1"/>
                                            <label for="1yes">YES</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="1"/>
                                            <label for="1no">NO</label>
                    </form></li>

<li>Question 2      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="2"/>
                                            <label for="2yes">YES</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="2"/>
                                            <label for="2no">NO</label>
                    </form></li>

<li>Question 3      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="3"/>
                                            <label for="3yes">YES</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="3"/>
                                            <label for="3no">NO</label>
                    </form></li>

<li>Question 4      <form><class="right"> <input type="radio" name="4"/>
                                            <label for="4yes">YES</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="4"/>
                                            <label for="4no">NO</label>
                    </form></li>
```

By adding a label, you are able to pair up the radios whilst still being able to uniquely identify the option that the user has selected.

Let me know if you need more clarification! Hope this helped you, here's the codepen link for you to see a live demo: https://codepen.io/designkenal/pen/OdQQmB